# php + apache + tomcat

Tags: php, apache-2.2, tomcat

I installed PHP, Apache, Tomcat in Cent OS 5

Tomcat and Apache work fine together.

But PHP! that's problem.

The Source inside php is this

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?> //This works well only if the Filename is index.html but doesn't work if it's index.php..
```

I have short knowledge neither in linux and php.

Hope my question is in right form. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `httpd.conf` add a line like this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5
```

Then restart Apache and you're on your way :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make index.php as your default page add

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

inside your Apache Virtualhost entry.